# Stream failing to close C#

Tags: c#, file, filestream, memorystream

I am creating a program which takes passwords and applies an encoding on them onto a file which I have *creatively* labeled a PASSWORDFILE file. I am a self taught amateur programmer and this is my first time using streams => I'm sorry my code isn't cleaner. When I add a password to my file, the file refuses to open (giving me a "System.IO.IOException: The process cannot access the file '[file path here]' because it is being used by another process."). I have made sure I am closing all my streams yet this error still persists.

To add further confusion:

```
namespace PasswordSaver
{
    [Serializable]
    class Password
    {
        public string ID;
        string baseWord;
        public Password(string password, string ID)
        {
            this.ID = ID;
            baseWord = password;
        }
        public virtual string GetPassword()
        {
            return baseWord;
        }
    }

    [Serializable]
    class EncodedPassword : Password
    {
        EncoderAndDecoder Encoder;

        public EncodedPassword(string decodedBasePassword, string ID) : base(decodedBasePassword, ID)
        {
            Encoder = new EncoderAndDecoder();
        }

        public override string GetPassword()
        {
            return Encoder.Encode(base.GetPassword(), out _);
        }
    }

    [Serializable]
    class EncodedPasswordWithAddendum : EncodedPassword
    {
        string addendum;
        public EncodedPasswordWithAddendum(string decodedBasePassword, string addendum, string ID) : base(decodedBasePassword, ID)
        {
            this.addendum = addendum;
        }
        public override string GetPassword()
        {
            return base.GetPassword() + addendum;
        }
    }
}
```

the error only occurs when I attempt to add an `EncodedPassword` or `EncodedPasswordWithAddendum` instances but not a `Password` instance.
My writing code is

```
namespace PasswordSaver
{
    class PasswordWriter
    {
        public readonly string saveFilePath;
        static string directory = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();

        #region Constructors
        public PasswordWriter()
        {
            saveFilePath = directory + @"\PasswordSaver"
                + ".passwordfile";
        }
        public PasswordWriter(string saveFilePath)
        {
            this.saveFilePath = saveFilePath;
        }
        #endregion

        #region Individual Writing Functions
        private void WriteBinary(object objectToEncode)
        {
            WriteBinary(objectToEncode, out _);
        }
        private void WriteBinary(object objectToEncode, out Exception exception)
        {
            exception = null;
            try
            {
                IFormatter binaryFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();

                Stream fileStream = new FileStream(saveFilePath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
                Stream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();

                memoryStream.Position = memoryStream.Length;
                binaryFormatter.Serialize(memoryStream, objectToEncode);

                EncodeFromStream(ref memoryStream, ref fileStream);


                fileStream.Close();
                memoryStream.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                exception = e;
            }
        }
        #endregion

        #region File Read and Writing
        public void WriteFile(Password[] passwords)
        {
            if (File.Exists(saveFilePath))
            {
                Stream stream = new FileStream(saveFilePath, FileMode.Truncate, FileAccess.Write);
                stream.Close();
            }

            WriteBinary(passwords.Length);
            foreach (Password password in passwords)
            {
                WriteBinary(password);
            }
        }

        public void WriteToFile(Password password)
        {
            Password[] oldPasswords = ReadFile();
            Password[] passwords = new Password[oldPasswords.Length + 1];
            for (int i = 0; i < oldPasswords.Length; i++)
            {
                passwords[i] = oldPasswords[i];
            }
            passwords[oldPasswords.Length] = password;
            WriteFile(passwords);
        }

        public bool ReplacePassword(string oldPasswordID, Password newPassword)
        {
            Password[] passwords = ReadFile();
            for (int i = 0; i < passwords.Length; i++)
            {
                if (passwords[i].ID == oldPasswordID)
                {
                    passwords[i] = newPassword;
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }

        public Password[] ReadFile()
        {
            Stream fileStream = new FileStream(saveFilePath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Read);
            IFormatter binaryFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            Stream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();

            DecodeFromStream(ref fileStream, ref memoryStream);

            fileStream.Close();

            memoryStream.Position = 0;

            int length = (int) binaryFormatter.Deserialize(memoryStream);
            //Console.WriteLine(length + " is the length");//debug
            Password[] passwords = new Password[length];
            for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
            {
                //Console.WriteLine(memoryStream.Position + " " + memoryStream.Length);//debug
                //Console.WriteLine(i);//debug
                passwords[i] = (Password)binaryFormatter.Deserialize(memoryStream);
            }

            memoryStream.Close();
            return passwords;
        }
        #endregion

        #region Encode and Decode
        private void EncodeFromStream(ref Stream stream, ref Stream newStream)
        {

            stream.Position = 0;
            newStream.Position = newStream.Length;


            for (int i = 0; i < stream.Length; i++)
            {
                int integer = stream.ReadByte();
                byte originalByte = (byte)integer;// get a byte off of the line
                //Encode byte here
                newStream.WriteByte(setOfBits1);
                newStream.WriteByte(setOfBits2);
            }
        }

        private void DecodeFromStream(ref Stream stream, ref Stream newStream)
        {
            newStream.Position = newStream.Length;

            stream.Position = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < (stream.Length / 2); i++)// stream.Length / 2 because the program reads two bytes per iteration of the for loop
            {
                //I decode the bytes here
                newStream.WriteByte(originalByte);
            }

        }
        #endregion
        public void WriteContentsToFile()
        {
            Stream stream = new FileStream(saveFilePath + "1", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
            Stream stream1 = new FileStream(saveFilePath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
            this.DecodeFromStream(ref stream1, ref stream);
            stream.Close();
            stream1.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

*I have removed the code that encoded and decoded the streams in `EncodeFromStream` and `DecodeFromStream`.
any occurrence of `new FileStream(saveFilePath + "1", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite)` is a where I was writing to a seperate file in a decoded format. To distinguish the two files I changed the file type from PASSWORDFILE to PASSWORDFILE1.*

In Conclusion:
I am using the `WriteFile` or `WriteToFile` methods with a `Password[]` that contains an `EncodedPassword` or `EncodedPasswordWithAddendum`. then when I try to open the file through a `FileStream` (usually through the method `ReadFile`) I get the Exception "System.IO.IOException: The process cannot access the file '[file path here]' because it is being used by another process".

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Side note: never `Close` stream **explicty**, but wrap in `using`: `using (Stream stream = new FileStream(...)) {}`

Comment: You need to avoid calling `Close` explicitly. Instead, wrap the use of each `Stream` in a `using` block.

Comment: Make sure that no external applications locks your file. See: https://helpcenter.gsx.com/hc/en-us/articles/115015880627-How-to-Identify-which-Windows-Process-is-Locking-a-File-or-Folder (Process Explorer is safe to use - it's created by Microsoft)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Streams usually contain unamanged resources (the OS Filehandles), so they implement IDisposeable.

While you can always be certain that the GC will clean up disposeable stuff *eventually* (latest at application closing), usually that is way to late. You have to do it explicitly. And for that I have a one rule regarding IDisposeable stuff:

"Never split up the creation and disposing of a disposeable resource. Create. Use. Dispose. All in the same piece of code, ideally using a using block."
The only exception I ever encountered a logfiles. Nothing else is *remotely* worth the trouble and headaches of keeping something disposeable open. Especially not performance.

As the [using block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement) uses a try...finally, you can be certain it will run. Compiler and runtime make certain finally blocks always run, even on function return, jump via goto or Exception cases.